# Condition in template by store records

Tags: templates, extjs

I am have template in view. This is my template:

```
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<tpl if="active">checked="checked">',
        '<div style="margin-left: 5px;">',
            '</br><b>{name}</b>',
        '</div>',
        '<div style="margin-left: 25px;">',
            '<span>{[Book]}: {book}</span>',
            '<br/><span>{[Price]}: {price}</span>',
            '<br/><span>{[Year]}: {year}</span>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
```

I want in this template output only records with data in field 'Year' = 2014, other records I do not want to show

Comment: You can filter your store

Comment: i am use this store in other places and i need all data of store everytime

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: If you're using Ext5+ you should use a chained store.

Comment: thanks i am use 6.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *can* be done, but I strongly advise against it.

Why do I advise against it? Common sense and ExtJS patterns tell us that everything from the store should be displayed, and when something should be invisible, the store should filter it out, not the view.

That said, after you have fixed the bugs in your template (the template as it is now does not produce valid HTML!), you could go forward and just add a `tpl if`, very similar to the one you already did:

```
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<tpl if="Year!=2014"> style="display:hidden"</tpl>">'
    '<tpl if="active">checked="checked">',
    ...
```